# How do I render React on the server with prerendered initial state?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

How could I create something like a homepage for a chat site in React where the server's React response includes initial data like chat messages? Do I need Redux for this?

Comment: If I get what you mean, no you dont need redux for that, if it's a static data you just add it to a json, variable or soon and than load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need data, you could send it along with the Html file.

index.html:

```
<script>
var initialState = /* have the server render some JSON here */
</script>
```

And then use "initialState" to populate the first screen. If you are using Redux you could use that variable as the initial state of your store. But as mentioned in the comments, Redux is not necessary for this; arguably it makes it easier to do so.

---

For true server-side rendering you would actually send a full Html page containing all Html and data already to match exactly what your SPA would generate.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! Do you mean for "true server-side rendering" I'd build up my react components embedded in the html with a string and in the class state just hard-set it to whatever my data is, instead of pointing it at the initialState object? Also, do you think it would be better to do CSR for this and have the client request the data, since I'll be communicating a lot with the server for this app anyway?

Comment: You'd build up your react components on the server and return the component tree as a Html string. From then on your SPA could take over.